# Density plot scaled on 0-1 in R

Tags: r, density-plot

Without using ggplot / ggplot2, is there a way to display normalized densities in R (y axis bounded between 0 and 1) ?

For example, with hist we can do the following:

```
# for any sample data x, on the interval num1, num2
num1 = 0.0
num2 = 1.0     
x <- rbeta(1000, 3, 7)
h = hist(x, breaks = 15)
h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts)
plot(h, freq=F)
```

I am looking for an equivalent to represent the pdf of x:

```
dx = 0.01
xd = seq(num1, num2, dx)
dist = dbeta(xd,3,7)
lines(xd,dist)   # will give me a density that deosnt scale with the histogram...
```

Same issue (ie. max(dist) > 1 ) if I plot dist separately.

Comment: hist(x,breaks=15) and directly after lines(density(x)) produces a plot in which a density curve fits the density histogram. The density curve values go higher than one because its making the total area equal to 1

Comment: Just plot `dist/max(dist)`

Comment: Thank you both. However, it doesnt give me the result I am expecting, For @MatiasAndina's solution, I get a density plot that doesnt match "dist" (it is probably evaluating a kernel density and doesnt correspond exactly to dbeta(xd,3,7).

Comment: As for @BondedDust 's solution, sum(dx* dist/ max(dist)) is not 1.0. The area under the pdf of x should be 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You may manipulate the y-axis for density plots:

```
d   = density(data)
d$y = d$y/max(d$y)

plot(d)
```

The y-axis will be bounded between zero and one.